# Can the hundred abdominal pilates build abs muscles?

Tags: bodybuilding

I'm wondering if the hundred Pilate's just sculpts and tones the abs muscles or induces hypertrophy in them.

Answer (score 1):

The hundred is an isometric abdominal exercise like the plank, pike pulses, V holds and L sits.

They serve very clear reasons

1. Specificity, Isometric Abdominal exercise translate well into heavy squats, deadlifts and olympic gymnastics
2. Abdominal control, isometrics really work the Pyramidalis which is the muscle that controls the line dividing your abdominals. Having a stronger Pyramidalis means have a deeper cut between your abs and more controll of them.

As for muscular growth, yes it will work wonders.
It has been shown several times that isometrics or partial repetitions focusing on the lengthened part of the muscle build muscle more efficiently than peak contraction holds and almost as much as full range of motion.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply. Idk why they down voted.

Comment: But aren't more reps against theory of failure?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. You meed to treat abdominal muscles like every other muscle. Building abs and showing them off are two different things. You’ll have abdominal muscles  if you workout for it irrespective of the fact that that you are obese or not. But they’ll be visible only when you have very little to no fat layer on your stomach. So don’t go for these “x” reps per day things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to treat abdominal muscles like every other muscle. Building abs and showing them off are the same thing, abdominal muscles(specially the obliques and serratus) are visible even at 20%-25% bodyfat, look up to  fat strongman, powerlifters and weightlifters they might not have chiseled abdominals but they are huge and clearly visible behind all that belly fat.

So yeah, do the hundred as it will build your abdomen but there is more than one way to build muscle, if you get a muscle under tension it will grow no matter how you do it.